# How to write the summation limits

Tags: equations

I am trying to write an equation `y[i]=1/M ∑_(j=0)^(M-1)x [i+j]` where lower summation limit is `j=0` and upper is `M-1`. I have tried with

```
\begin{equation}\label{moving average}
 $$y[i]=\frac{1}{M}\sum_j=0^(M-1)x[i+j]$$
\end{equation}
```

but the limits on the summation symbol is not coming?

Comment: equation is a math environment, remove the `$` and you need braces `\sum_{j=0}^{(m-1)} x[i+j]`

Comment: OK, so only { } works. I was trying with ( ). Just started with Latex. Lot to learn. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

David Carlisle's comment looks more like an answer to me.  But here is some code and the resultant output, which should suffice to close this question out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  y[i]=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{j=0}^{M-1} x[i+j] \label{moving-average}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]